# How does one generate an image of a sine wave with (h,k) indices (2,2)?

Tags: fourier-analysis, image-processing, crystallography

I am trying to generate an image of a gradient that oscillates $h$ times along the $x$-axis and $k$ times along the $y$-axis.

As an example, this image I generated below oscillates $5$ times along the $x$-axis, and $0$ times along the $y$-axis:

### $f(x) = \sin(5x + 0)$

The image below on the left is the sum of two waves: one wave $(h, k) = (4, 4)$, and the other with $(h, k) = (-20, 19)$

[image]

The images I want to generate are just an array of 100x100 pixels. I can't seem to figure out how to make the wave travel diagonally. The diagonal waves cut each respective axis into a number of pieces -- this is what defines the h and k index.

To generate the one on the right, I simply made an array that is $100$ values and applied the function above on those values.

Apologies if this is the wrong forum to post on! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $f(x)=\sin(x)$ completes one period on $[0,2\pi]$.

Therefore $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ completes one period on $[0,1]$.

Then $f(x)=\sin(2\pi hx)$ completes $h$ periods on the interval $[0,1]$.

In the plane use $f(x,y)=\sin(2\pi hx+2\pi yk)$.

On interval $[0,100]\times[0,100]$ it is $f(x,y)=\sin(200\pi hx+200\pi yk)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I understand everything you're saying... I think my difficulty now is how to implement it programatically.

Comment: I guess I could just iterrate over the rows of a 100x100 grid. In the first row I set y = 1, and treat each element as x = 1, x = 2, x = 3, etc. So, that is 10,000 calculations per wave image

Comment: @Vranvs If you are really concerned by efficiency, you could use the periodicity to make the algorithm faster. In your first image, for example, you only need to call the function $f$ total $20$ times on the bottom right. The remaining pixels are copies of those $20$. However for a $100\times 100$ image this doesn't seem like a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted M. Nestor's answer -- here is the final result

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from random import seed
from random import random
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Globals
resolution = 1000

#Get a random HK plane
def rdmHK():
    return(round(random()*15))

#Get a random amplitude
def rdmAmp():
    return(random()*100)

#Wave generator
def waveGenerator(h, k, a, phi, res):
    mesh = np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: a*np.sin(2*np.pi*h*x/res + 2*np.pi*k*y/res + phi), shape = (res,res))
    return mesh

#Make a blank image, 1000x1000
img = np.zeros((resolution, resolution))

#Add together 100 random waves of various resolutions
for x in range(15):
    img = np.add(img, waveGenerator(rdmHK(), rdmHK(), rdmAmp(), 0, resolution))
    print('added wave ' + str(x))

wave = waveGenerator(1,1,1,0,resolution)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```